# How can I build real time system in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, real-time

I am building an asp.net application for a health care domain. I need to keep the page to reflect real time updates. One way is to refresh the page after every x minutes but it may increase the load if there is no update. Moreover doing like this may not get the exact real time data. I want to achieve the almost complete real time functionality. 
How it can be done in ASP.NET C#..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at SignalR https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR and http://www.hanselman.com/blog/AsynchronousScalableWebApplicationsWithRealtimePersistentLongrunningConnectionsWithSignalR.aspx
I think it is just what you need.

Comment: @Wim..I saw some tutorials using SignalR. But they shows it with MVC applications. Is it possible to use SignalR with Non-MVC applications? Is there good tutorial to start with....?

Comment: I have seen SignalR work with just an html page and some classes so SignalR can definitely be used outside of MVC. I think the nuget SignalR.Sample package is just html. I don't know of any good tutorials. Go to http://jabbr.net/ and ask in the signalr chatroom.

Comment: Do I need to make any change at the server if I deploy my application which uses SignalR...?